# Unknown struct error in C++ while compiling with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, constructor, g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int Answer;
struct _pair {
    struct _pair(int a) : value(a), cnt(1) {}
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int cnt;
    };


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    return 0;
}
```

this code occurs error :
"error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
struct _pair(int a) : value(a), cnt(1) {}"

It makes no error on VS2017, but it makes an error on GCC compiler.

Comment: There shouldn't be `struct` in `struct _pair(int a) : value(a), cnt(1) {}`.

Comment: Also: `using namespace std;` in combination with a symbol prefix `_` might give you all kinds of weird compiler errors.

Comment: That's a global namespace underscore prefix, so `using namespace std;` isn't required to wreak havoc. It just makes things worse. More info here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor doesn't need the `struct` qualifier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int Answer;
struct _pair {
   _pair(int a) : value(a), cnt(1) {}
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int cnt;
};
```